# Передача файла через Intent в Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-intent

У меня есть 2 девайса, 1 на Android Lollipop, 2 - Oreo. 
На 1 девайсе: с любого места отправляю(кнопкой Share) файл(mp3) в приложение, которое должно принять его.
Манифест:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

В активити принимаю так:

```
        String[] query = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
        MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST };

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Log.d("IntentStatus", "" + intent);
        String author;
        String track;


        Uri audioUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        if (audioUri != null) {
            tempCursor = getContentResolver().query(audioUri,
                query, null, null, null);
            Log.d("QueryStatus", "" + tempCursor);
        }

        tempCursor.moveToFirst();
        int index;
        do {
            index = tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            track = tempCursor.getString(index);
            index = tempCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST);
            author = tempCursor.getString(index);
            Log.d("AuthorTrack", "  " + track + " : " + author);

        } while(tempCursor.moveToNext());
```

Все работает нормально, но на 2 девайсе - нет. Пробовал запрашивать права на доступ к памяти, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: а вы уверены что `intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)` возвращает нужные вам значения? я бы на вашем месте весть код включая работу с курсором засунул в условие `audioUri!=null`